# is it Possible to convert RenderFragment to a string?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am attempting to pass the ChildContent of a child component which is a RenderFragment to it's parent component method as a string parameter.

The component structure is:

```
<MySelect>
  <MySelectOption Value="Value 1">Text1</MySelectOption>
  <MySelectOption Value="Value 2">Text2</MySelectOption>
</MySelect>
```

I could easily solve this by passing the text as a parameter into MySelectOption which I cou8ld then send back to the parent method (MySelect).  However I wondered if it would be poissible to simply convert the ChildContent of the MySelectOption to a string as this would only ever be text.

Comment: **NO**.  A render fragment is a `delegate` that fits the pattern `void method(RenderTreeBuilder builder)`.  The Razor compiler takes your markup and converts it into a RenderFragment delegate that the Renderer then uses to build the component output.    Where/How will you use this "String"?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I am developing a custom select dropdown component, therefore the idea is that when the user clicks a div in the MyOptionSelect, it's text content (ChildContent) is sent to the parent MySelect component so It can update it's display.  But It seems ultimately my problem is I need to get Content of the option as a string if I do not wish to use parameters.

Comment: In the end I managed to this by passing the RenderFragment itself as the parameter which updates a RenderFragment instance in the parent which accomplishes the same result I was hoping for